# Google Translate API not recognising special characters

Tags: python-3.x, google-api

I am using the google translate code below

```
def translate_text(text):
    
    if isinstance(text, six.binary_type):
        text = text.decode("utf-8")
        
    output= translate_client.translate(
        text,
        target_language= 'en')    

    return output['translatedText']
```

when running the following code:

```
print(translate_text(' can\'t modify account id and l\'y faut utiliser l\'id de marc'))
```

i am getting the following output

```
"can&#39;t modify account id and use marc&#39;s id"
```

instead of

```
"can't modify account id and use marc's id"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the Answer, had to add an additional parameter to the function

```
def translate_text(text):
    
    if isinstance(text, six.binary_type):
        text = text.decode("utf-8")

    output= translate_client.translate(
        text,
        format_='text', # <---- by default the value is HTML
        target_language= 'en')    

    return output['translatedText']
```